# Running Fortify on .dll files as well as .cs

Tags: c#, security, dll, fortify

.NET version of existing question [Can I run fortify on .jar files instead of .java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278390/can-i-run-fortify-on-jar-files-instead-of-java)

My team is using Fortify 5.15.0.0060. We are scanning our .NET project in Visual Studio, and project settings shows the following command line arguments:

```
-vsversion 10.0 "-b" "project" "-machine-output" "-scan" "-f" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Fortify\VS2010-3.80\project\Scan.fpr" "-format" "fpr"
```

This highlights issues in our .cs source code files, but does not appear to look at the DLLs that form part of our solution (and which are copied to our output directory along with our binaries). For many of these libraries we do not have access to .pdb files, but were hoping that Fortify would be able to do a limited amount of scanning anyway.

Is it possible to add a command line argument to include DLL files, with/without PDB files?

Comment: Afaik, Fortify only has a source code scanner, not a decompiler.  You could help and decompile DLLs yourself with a tool like Reflector or ILSpy.  Do beware the questionable benefit of getting warnings that you cannot fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to .Net, Fortify can only scan assemblies that have a .pdb because it uses `ildasm.exe` to decompile the assembly and then it uses the .pdb to match to the source files.  Unfortunately there is no way for you to scan these extra assemblies.

If you have the .pdb files, you can have Fortify scan them, however you may not see the full source in your results.  To include these assemblies, you need to specify them in your Translation options.  If you are doing this all from the command line, then this is how you would do it:

```
sourceanalyzer -b project -vsversion 10.0 projectPath\Additional.Assembly.1.dll projectPath\Additional.Assembly.2.dll projectPath\Additional.Assembly.3.dll
sourceanalyzer -b project -scan -f MyResults.fpr
```

If you have not yet updated your Fortify version, I would highly recommend that you do so.

Comment: Can I use something like this, `**/**/*.dll`, or this, `**/*.dll`, for finding all .dll files?